# Convert table of individual events-distances into a summary table of events

Tags: mysql

Two weeks ago I started learning SQL and it has been going pretty good so far but I have run into a situation that I can't seem to resolve.  After two days of searching the web and looking at books, I am no closer to solving this issue, so time to ask for some help.  Part of my problem is that being so new to SQL I'm not exactly sure what to search for.

This is using mySQL and INNODB.

After some joins and other things I have the table below with athlete information giving the type of event in which the athlete participated and the distance of that event.  The possible event/distance combinations are {A10,A15,B10,B15}.

Events Table

```
last_name   first_name  event   distance
Munster     Eddie       A       10
Brady       Marsha      A       10
Clampet     Jethro      B       15
Grumby      Jonas       A       15
Brady       Peter       A       10
Brady       Marsha      A       10
Brady       Marsha      B       15
Grant       Ginger      B       15
Munster     Eddie       B       10
Brady       Marsha      A       10
```

What I am trying to do as the final step is to transform this table into a form that shows how many times each athlete participated in each event, like the following output:

```
last_name   first_name  A10     A15     B10     B15
Munster     Eddie       1       0       1       0
Brady       Marsha      3       0       0       1
Clampet     Jethro      0       0       0       1
Grumby      Jonas       0       1       0       0
Brady       Peter       1       0       0       0
Grant       Ginger      0       0       0       1
```

I think I want to use correlated subqueries, so I have tried a number variants of this following SQL query but it returns "Operand should contain 1 column(s)", which makes sense.

```
SELECT last_name, first_name,
count(if(event='A',1,0) AND if(distance=10,1,0)) AS A10
FROM sample s
WHERE (SELECT last_name, first_name, event, distance
  FROM sample s1
  WHERE s1.last_name = s.last_name
  )
ORDER BY last_name, first_name;
```

The steps I see I need are:
1. create a set of each name in the table, which I can do, and then 
2. iterate through each name, creating a new query selecting event/distance and then 
3. summing that query on event/distance combination;
4. return the result back up to #1.

I see that procedures provide some looping capabilities, is that the way to do this?  Is what I want to do possible in the SQL environment?  My next step is to just dump the raw table to PHP and process it there.

Any thoughts and/or solutions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Consider returning a simple ordered list and handling remaining issues of data display at the application level if you have one (e.g., a PHP loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT last_name, 
       first_name, 
       count(if(event = 'A', 1, NULL) 
             AND if(distance = 10, 1, NULL)) AS A10, 
       count(if(event = 'A', 1, NULL) 
             AND if(distance = 15, 1, NULL)) AS A15, 
       count(if(event = 'B', 1, NULL) 
             AND if(distance = 10, 1, NULL)) AS B10, 
       count(if(event = 'B', 1, NULL) 
             AND if(distance = 15, 1, NULL)) AS B15 
FROM   sample s 
GROUP  BY last_name, 
          first_name 
ORDER  BY last_name, 
          first_name;
```

Comment: Gidil, I am sorry to ask this, but are you sure that field and table names should be in upper case? I agree that functions should be (sorry, just copied from the original post). But currently all the query is uppercase. It seems to be useless.

Comment: The uppercase isn't really important, the query layout is (IMHO) important. I reverted part of the change I made.

Comment: Gidil, thank you for the quick and detailed responses. I spent yesterday going back and relearning GROUP BY.  Clearly I didn't understand it when I thought I did.  None of the SQL books I have found have been particularly good.  Do you have any recommendations for a good learning SQL book?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the `SUM + CASE` syntax.
Try something like this:

```
SELECT LAST_NAME, 
       FIRST_NAME, 
       SUM(CASE 
             WHEN EVENT = 'A' 
                  AND DISTANCE = 10 THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           END) AS A10, 
       SUM(CASE 
             WHEN EVENT = 'A' 
                  AND DISTANCE = 15 THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           END) AS A15, 
       SUM(CASE 
             WHEN EVENT = 'B' 
                  AND DISTANCE = 10 THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           END) AS B10, 
       SUM(CASE 
             WHEN EVENT = 'B' 
                  AND DISTANCE = 15 THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           END) AS B15 
FROM   SAMPLE 
GROUP  BY LAST_NAME, 
          FIRST_NAME
```

You can find a working example on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac7d8/17).

Good Luck!